# Regex and ReplaceAll in Velocity to extract text

Tags: regex, velocity

in Velocity I have:

```
#set( $text = "#parse('file url')" )
```

What I would like is to extract only the text inside the div called "paragrafo-html".

File content and regex are here:

https://regex101.com/r/wr8H04/1

I have wrote:

```
$text.replaceAll('(?:.|\\n)*?<div class="paragrafo-html" style="">((?:.|\\n)*?)</div>(?:.|\\n)*', '$1')
```

but it doesn't work while regex group seems to me right.

Also:

```
$text.matches('(?:.|\n)*?<div class="paragrafo-html" style="">(?:.|\n)*?</div>(?:.|\n)*')
```

give me error.

Could you suggest me what I am doing wrong in replaceAll?

Comment: `(?:.|\n)*?` is NEVER right, never use it. If you see this pattern in any regex, avoid using it altogether. Use `(?s)` at the pattern start and all `.` in the regex pattern (outside of character classes and those not escaped) will match newlines.

Comment: I add that trying to match a <div> that way may not be good idea, unless you are very sure its content never includes any other nested <div>.

Comment: In general, using a full string matching regex method to extract a part of the string is a bad idea due to heavy backtracking. Use `.find()` to extract a part of a string.

Comment: If you are desperate , try `(?s).*?<div\\s+class="paragrafo-html"\\s+style="">(.*?)</div>.*` with replaceAll, but if possible, check the `find` availability in Velocity.

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor Stribizew last comment works! So:

```
$text.replaceAll('(?s).*?<div\s+class="paragrafo-html"\s+style="">(.*?)</div>.*', '$1')
```

Thanks!